# Split data from matrix with names

Tags: r

I have a 42*14 matrix (5 * 14 as the example below). Are there any approaches I can split the data into 42 individual data sets (vector) and at the same time name them from subject 1 to subject 42?

```
#expected result (I need subject1 to subject5)
subject1 <- structure(list(`1` = 0L, `2` = 0L, `3` = 1L, `4` = 1L, `5` = 0L, 
                               `6` = 0L, `7` = 1L, `8` = 1L, `9` = 0L, `10` = 1L, `11` = 1L, 
                               `12` = 0L, `13` = 1L, `14` = 0L), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("data.table", 
                                                                                                  "data.frame"))





 structure(list(`1` = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), `2` = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                    0L, 1L), `3` = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), `4` = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                  0L), `5` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `6` = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
               `7` = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), `8` = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), 
               `9` = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), `10` = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), 
               `11` = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), `12` = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L
               ), `13` = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), `14` = c(0L, NA, NA, 1L, 
                                                         0L)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
                                                         ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `list2env` assuming your `matrix` is named *x*.

```
list2env(setNames(asplit(x, 1),
 paste0("subject", seq_len(nrow(x)))), globalenv())

ls()
#[1] "subject1" "subject2" "subject3" "subject4" "subject5" "x"       

subject1
# 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 
# 0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  1  1  0  1  0
```

In case you want to remove also `NA`:

```
list2env(setNames(lapply(asplit(x, 1), Filter, f = Negate(is.na)),
 paste0("subject", seq_len(nrow(x)))), globalenv())

subject2
# 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 
# 1  1  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0
```

Answer (score 1):

You want each row as one element in the list, right?

Might be prettier solutions out there, but this would do the trick:

```r
l <- lapply(
    1:nrow(your.data),
    function(i){
        j <- !is.na(your.data[i,])
        return( your.data[i,which(j)] )
    }
)

names(l) <- paste0( "subject", 1:length(l) )
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! Can I at the same time delete NA? So that they will have different number of columns depends on how many NA they have.